# My findContours() function behaves abnormally on images with different dpi

Tags: c++, opencv

Here are the results of `findContours()` on two similar images. They have the same resolutions(1920x1080) but different DPIs(96 and 300).

[image: DPI300]
[image: DPI96]
As you can see, the result on the higher dpi input gives me a contour size of 20, which is correct, while the low dpi one just gives me weird result.

The arguments that I gave were: `findContours(gray, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)`

Is this something to do with the `CV_RETR_LIST` mode?

Many thanks in advance:)

Comment: It looks like if the second image has some noise next to the spheres. Maybe these pixels are not pure black. You can try to do a threshold to the gray image you pass to findContours... not a hard one, probably something like 10 is enough

Comment: @api55 yeah it worked. That noise comes from the compression I guess. Thanks

Comment: Yes, similar problem happens when one saves it as a jpeg... the compression creates some artifacts. I will write it as an answer then

Comment: Ya, X-Y problem. Since OpenCV works with the individual pixels, DPI metadata is irrelevant -- you'll get the same 1920x1080 pixels, no matter what the DPI. The noise on the second image (as @api55 points out) is likely from a lossy codec used sometime in its history. (TBH, using JPEG on such synthetic image is kinda silly in the first place)

Comment: @DanMašek Thanks for your comment. I’m pretty new to image compression, but say if I have pure black and white binarized images (since the image is still 8-bit, black would be 0 and white 255, I think I’m right on this part), is there a preferred format of the image that prevents giving me unclear edges?

Comment: @ZacharySun Anything lossless. PNG is often a decent choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a lot of cases of compression, such as saving a JPEG image or changing the DPI, can generates some artifacts which are almost invisible to the human eye. Usually it is between two colors. For example in your image, the spheres have a color and the background is black. around the colored ones, you will have some almost black pixels.

You can always suppress these pixels using a threshold function. This most be done before it is passed to the findContours function.

Since the pixels are almost black, it is enough to set the threshold quite low, like 10.